# Preparing a view of numpy array (without memory overhead)

Tags: arrays, numpy

I've noticed that recovering the values of an array based on indices is relatively slow compared to simply return a full array. See for instance:

```py
a = np.random.rand(10000)
mask = np.random.choice([0, 1], 10000).astype(bool)
b = a[mask]
%timeit a[mask]
56.1 µs ± 2.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
idx = np.arange(10000)[mask]
%timeit a[idx]
6.64 µs ± 361 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit b
19.4 ns ± 0.956 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

In this example, indexing (with mask or actual indices) seems to take a thousand time longer than direct recovering of the sub-array of interest.

I understand this is the result of O(n) complexity to recover all the n elements specified in the index (or bool) array. However, in the case when I need to access the same sub-array multiple times in a loop, I would like to pay this price only once and not at each iteration. I could make a temporary copy of that sub-array, as I did in my example, but it would induce a memory overhead which I am not willing to pay.

I think it should be possible to only store a view (not a copy) of `a[idx]` in `b` but I cannot figure how.

Comment: `view` is a technical term for what `numpy` produces with `reshape` and a subset of indexing operations (`basic indexing`).  You are doing `advanced indexing`.

Comment: `timeit b` doesn't 'recover' `b` or its elements.  `timeit a` would time the same.  It's just a python variable access.

Comment: Better check what `b` (or `idx`) values are.  (or its `shape`).  I don't think this `mask` is doing what you intend.  `mask` is not a boolean array.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I fixed the problem with the boolean array. However this does not solve the issue. You are right, `%timeit b` only times variable accession. Like a view I guess. If I do `%timeit a[:5000]`, it takes much less time than `a[idx]` this is because `a[idx]` makes a copy so read and write operations whereas a[:5000] makes a view. I would like to have only read.

Comment: A low cost `view` is possible when the selection can be expressed in terms of `shape`, `strides` (and possibly at change in pointer to the share databuffer).  With boolean mask, or indexing array, such a `view` is impossible; it has to make a new array with its own data.  A `numpy` array does not carry any record of how it was created, whether via indexing or reshaping.

Comment: Normally there isn't a distinction between read_only and read_write copies or views.  There is a `read_only` flag that can be set, but that's only used in some specialized code.